# TSQL: how to select the client status in the date2 closest to date1 (date1 can be either much else less date2)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Let's assume, we have a clients table:

```
client  acctraction_dt  status     status_dt    date_diff
a       21.05.2019      big        13.05.2019   8
a       21.05.2019      small      22.05.2019   -1
a       21.05.2019      medium     25.05.2019   -4
b       01.04.2019      big        13.05.2019   -42
b       01.04.2019      small      22.05.2019   -51
b       01.04.2019      medium     25.05.2019   -54
c       01.06.2019      big        13.05.2019   19
c       01.06.2019      small      22.05.2019   10
c       01.06.2019      medium     25.05.2019   7
```

I want to define, what status did a client have in the date of attraction in the company through the following logic:

a) if date_diff of some client < 0 and > 0, we should take max(date_diff) from the negative dates we have, i.e. the date closest to attraction date except positive.

b) If min(date_diff) of some client <= 0, we should take max(date_diff), from the dates we have - i.e. the date closest to attraction date.

c) If min(date_diff) of some client > 0,  whe should take min(date_diff) from the dates we have, i.e. the date closest to attraction date.

Desirable result is:

client a - **small** since min(date_diff) is negative. And max date between min dates (-1 and -4) is -1

client b - **big** since min(date_diff) is negative. And max date between dates (-42, -51, -54) is -42

client c - **medium** since min(date_diff) is positive. And min date between dates (7, 10, 19) is 7

I've tried a lot to use min, max and over ... partition for multiple times, but stucked.

Thank you very much for help.

Comment: Why isn't the "status" column good enough to know the status? 
 What "company"?  Desired results would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewriting your conditions to make them more easily readable:

- If the **minimum** `date_diff` for a client is positive, we will take that `date_diff` value.
- In **any other case**, we will take the `date_diff` value which is the closest to zero among the negative ones for that client.

So this is one possible query:

```
SELECT c.Client, 
CASE WHEN (SELECT MIN(date_diff) FROM Clients WHERE client = c.client) > 0
    THEN (SELECT MIN(date_diff) FROM Clients WHERE client = c.client)
    ELSE (SELECT TOP 1 date_diff FROM Clients WHERE client = c.client
            AND date_diff <= 0 ORDER BY date_diff DESC)
END AS AttractionStatus
FROM Clients c
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `CTE` to generate the minimum and maximum date differences, and the maximum negative date difference for each client, and then `JOIN` the `CTE` back to the `clients` table to get the client status using the algorithm you have supplied:

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT client, 
         MIN(date_diff) AS min_diff, 
         MAX(date_diff) AS max_diff,
         MAX(CASE WHEN date_diff < 0 THEN date_diff END) AS max_neg
  FROM clients
  GROUP BY client
)
SELECT c.client,
       c.status
FROM CTE
JOIN clients c ON c.client = CTE.client AND c.date_diff =
  CASE WHEN CTE.min_diff < 0 AND CTE.max_diff > 0 THEN CTE.max_neg
       WHEN CTE.min_diff <= 0 THEN CTE.max_diff
       ELSE CTE.min_diff
  END
```

Output:

```
client  status
a       small
b       big
c       medium
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/30224/2)

Comment: Nick, thank you very much. I tried your code on the real data and saw many duplicates of clients and their status (in fact: len(dataset) * len(dataset)). What could cause that?

Comment: @AlexIvanov sorry - the sample data was so small I didn't notice I had left off the required `JOIN` condition on `client`. I've updated the answer and the demo.